# How to choose between NTCredentials and UsernamePasswordCredentials in a generic application?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm

I am developing an application which supports both basic and NTLM authentication proxy using apache HttpClient version 4.5.2. The user interface currently doesn't ask the user about the type of authentication in proxy and is assumed as NTLM if the user enters a domain like given below:

```
    Credentials credentials = null;
    if (domain != null && domain.length() > 0) {
        credentials = new NTCredentials(username, password, client, domain);
    else {
        credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    }
```

This approach was working in most cases. However, in one deployment where the NTLM proxy server was a part of a workgroup (not a part of a domain), the domain is null and by the logic above, the credential used was UsernamePasswordCredentials. Since the proxy supports NTLM and needs to have credential to be an instance of NTCredentials, the request failed.

Is there any way in which I can make this code generic like this in an NTLM proxy which is a part of a workgroup, without asking the user about the type of authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can just use `NTCredentials` with null domain as the only type of credentials regardless of the opposite endpoints being a part of NT domain or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you mean that we can use `NTCredentials` with null/valid domain (thereby completely avoiding the usage of `UsernamePasswordCredentials`) in conditions where the proxy uses (1) ntlm auth or (2) basic auth with the proxy may or may not be a part of a domain?

Comment: Use null domain value if domain is unknown. Otherwise just use NTCredentials instead of UsernamePasswordCredentials and live happily ever after